# run time check failure #3 - t within the while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

Hi I have a question regarding run time check failure #3 in my case..
I'm using two if statement within the while loop. 
I learned failure #3 causes by not initializing variable. However I did before a while loop. And first if statement works, but when it reaches second if statement it stops.. Please advice me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Justin

```
    int count = 0;

    while (1)
    { 
        cap >> src;

        if (count < 5)
        {
            cout << count << endl;
        }

        // error at the second if statement. 
        if (count == 4) 
        {
            cout << "here" << end;
            count = 0;
        }

        count += 1;

    }
```

Comment: it's a infinite loop.

Comment: Yes it is.. There were more functions, but for the sake of simplicity I removed them from my question.. Also infinite loop doesn't cause "run time check failure #3"..

Comment: i think you have miss spelled endl to end; is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @pirate, in your second if condition you have a spelling mistake.

```
    if (count == 4) 
    {
        cout << "here" << end; // instead of end use endl here
        count = 0;
    }
```

Tested your program and its working fine without any error.

Comment: I cant' believe it That was the problem!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JustinJungheeKim There is no rule to say thanks here, if solution works, then mark the answer as accepted or upvote, so that other users can take it as reference.